# Dygraphs not displaying correctly when loaded in a non-active tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dygraphs

I have a Dygraph set to render in a page with multiple tabs in Bootstrap. The tab with the graph is not selected by default, however I have it render when the page loads. Here's what happens:

[image]

The graph would otherwise load fine if it weren't for the tabs. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

The bug was really an issue of the div not being displayed, and dygraphs not knowing the proper width. If the window is resized with the dygraph displayed, it will show correctly. So, to remedy this:

```
$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    g.resize(); // resize the dygraph
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When a tab is hidden, then the width value of the div that corresponds to that tab has negative value. So depending on the use case it would make sense to create a graph wrapper div that gets its size by boostrap.

Afterwards when processing the resize window message give the graph div the width and height of a **visible** element and everything will work fine.

This is how I handled the problem in a real life scenario using Boostrap 3.

```
<!-- these are my tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li class="active"><a id="plot-tab-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#image">Graph Bitmap Image</a></li>
    <li><a id="dygraph-tab-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#dygraph">Dygraph</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- we want to display an image and a dygraph -->
<div class="tab-content col-sm-12">
    <div id="image" class="tab-pane active">
        <div id="plot-wrapper" class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <image src=""
                   class="best-fit-image"
                   alt="Loading image ... Please wait!" id="plot"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dygraph" class="tab-pane">
        <div id="graph-wrapper" class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <div id="graph"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my resize window function code.

```
const RESIZE_FACTOR = 0.7; // fix it accordingly

var resizeWindow = function() {
    var graphHeight = $(window).height() * RESIZE_FACTOR;
    var graphWidth;

    $('#plot-wrapper').height(graphHeight);
    $('#graph').height(graphHeight);

    graphWidth = $('#plot-wrapper').width();
    if (graphWidth <= 0)
        graphWidth = $('#graph-wrapper').width();
    $('#graph').width(graphWidth);

    if (graph)
        graph.resize();
};
```